# Can't open Brackets installed by flatpak

Tags: flatpak

I want to test `flatpak` because many people recommend it for me.
At the first try, I installed the package `Brackets`, but it failed, I can't open it.

I execute in a terminal:

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=brackets --file-forwarding io.brackets.Brackets @@ %F @@
```

and get this error

> error: runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/1.6 not installed`

Comment: What do you meant by "it failed to install"? It usually comes down to: `flatpak install flathub io.brackets.Brackets`, then just do `flatpak run io.brackets.Brackets` – or execute `Brackets` by clicking on the icon.

Comment: I mean it won't run

Comment: How do you installed Brackets? Assuming you have the `flatpak` package already installed, it's just a matter of executing `flatpak install flathub io.brackets.Brackets` and then running it, either from the terminal: `flatpak run io.brackets.Brackets`, or just clicking on the created icon in the desktop, etc. That will take care of all the required dependencies and what not, which is your case: `org.freedesktop.Sdk/1.6` — that's required.